# Executing PowerShell script on Python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, powershell

I am trying to execute the following Windows PowerShell script (`Get-Event-Logs.ps1`):

```bsh
Get-EventLog system -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) -Instance 44
```

It should output something like this:

```
Index Time          EntryType   Source                 InstanceID Message
----- ----          ---------   ------                 ---------- -------
21056 Nov 27 15:47  Information Microsoft-Windows...           44 Windows Update started downloading an update.
21045 Nov 27 15:23  Information Microsoft-Windows...           44 Windows Update started downloading an update.
21044 Nov 27 15:23  Information Microsoft-Windows...           44 Windows Update started downloading an update.
21043 Nov 27 15:23  Information Microsoft-Windows...           44 Windows Update started downloading an update.
21042 Nov 27 15:23  Information Microsoft-Windows...           44 Windows Update started downloading an update.
21005 Nov 27 12:18  Information Microsoft-Windows...           44 Windows Update started downloading an update.
20940 Nov 26 18:42  Information Microsoft-Windows...           44 Windows Update started downloading an update.
```

I am executing in python with the following code:

```python
import subprocess, sys
p = subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', 'Get-Event-Logs.ps1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
print(out)
```

All I'm getting is a blank.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Specify the path to the PowerShell script if its location isn't in your PATH. You may also want to use `['powershell.exe', '-File', 'Get-Event-Logs.ps1']`. Other than that the code should do what you expect. Did you verify that `Get-EventLog` actually returns a result?

Comment: Also, note that your whatever working dir. your Python script was started from is also the PowerShell process' working dir. By specifying neither `-file` nor `-command`, `-command` is the default, and looking for a script by mere file _name_ will only succeed if the script is in in a location in `$env:PATH`. If you use `-file`, specify a _path_ to the script file; e.g., if the assumption is that it is in the current dir.: `subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', '-file', './Get-Event-Logs.ps1']` ...)`